# Filter Dataframe using regular expression

Tags: python

I have a Dataframe with a column with values separated by semicolons eg. Patient1_Control2; Patient1_Patient3; Control1_Control3. However I only want the rows with PatientX_ControlX or ControlX_PatientX. I don't want ControlX_ControlX or PatientX_PatientX. I thought of the method `filter(regex = '...')` , but this does not quite do the job. I want to filter the dataframe by a regular expression where I can use the regular expression PatientX_ControlX or ControlX_PatientX (x meaning random string). Is there any method for that? Thanks so much in advance. I'm still learning how to code so every tip would be great. If you have any sources where i can learn more about regular expression, that'd be amazing!

Comment: If the value is `Patient1_Control2; Patient1_Patient3; Control1_Control3` you don't want this row? and if the value is `Patient1_Control2` you want the row? if it is `Patient1_Control2; Control2_Patient1`?

Comment: Yes, I don't want any rows that have either ```Patientx_Patientx``` or ```Controlx_Controlx```, but if the row only has ```Patientx_Controlx``` or ```Controlx_Patientx``` then I want to keep the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter the column `data` not to contain the relevant values -

```
df[~(df["data"].str.contains('Patient\d+_Control\d+|Control\d+_Patient\d+'))]
```

For the following the dataframe -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"data":["Patient1_Control2", "Patient1_Patient3", "Control1_Patient3", "Control1_Control3"]})

df[~(df["data"].str.contains('Patient\d+_Control\d+|Control\d+_Patient\d+'))]
```

Output is -

```
                data
1  Patient1_Patient3
3  Control1_Control3
```